# ydn.db valuesByIndex method support on windows universal

Tags: cordova, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-cordova, windows-10-mobile, ydn-db

In my cordova application I was using ydn.db. Method values was working fine. Now replaced it with valuesByIndex, which now fails. Does anybody know if ydn.db valuesByIndex method id fully supported on windows phone 10?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: When i removed the 3rd optional argument - keyRange - everything worked. With the 3rd argument - data was not fetched from indexeddb.